# Getting an error.. Get-wmiObject : access is denied

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I am actually fetching some basic system information for a remote desktop by using powershell but i am facing an error..

```
$remoteComputer = "IP address of the remote computer"

$desktopInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Computer SystemProduct -ComputerName $remoteComputer

$serialNumber = $desktopInfo. IdentifyingNumber

$model = $desktopInfo.Name

$systemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $remoteComputer

$systemName = $systemInfo.Name

$processorInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor -ComputerName $remoteComputer

$processorName= $processorInfo. Name

Write-Host "System Name: $systemName"

Write-Host "Processor Name: $processorName"

Write-Host "Serial Number: $serialNumber"

Write-Host "Model: Smodel"
```

[image: image of the error that i getting]

Please i am kinda new to powershell...If anyone has any idea please share it with me

Comment: The error tells you all you need to know - the account running the script doesn't have permissions to query WMI on the target computer.

Comment: If i get the admin password and username then it will work?? If yes then how will i integrate the credential with this code?? Please reply i really need some help on this

Comment: The target computer would have to have dcom or wsman/remote powershell (get-ciminstance) set up.

Comment: The WMI commands are deprecated in PowerShell Core. Use `Get-CimInstance`.

Comment: Get-CimInstance is also not working.I get the system requirement for one remote pc by using get-wmiobject but not with Get-CimInstance